# Chunk ruby string into section with regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a text file structured in sections that I would like to break up as an array with string elements for each section.  The content of each section will then be manipulated differently depending on the section.  I'm using irb at the moment and will most likely break this out to be a separate ruby script file.

I've created both a string object and file object from the input file ("sample" and "sample_file" respectively) to test out different methods.  I'm sure a file read loop cold work here but I believe a simple match is all I need.

The file looks like this:

```
*** Section Header ***

randomly formatted content
multiple lines

 *** Another Header (some don't end with asterisk and sometimes space will exist before the asterisk set)

This sections info
       **** sub headers sometime occur***
           I'm okay with treating this as normal headers for now.
           I think sub headers may have something consistent about them.


*** Header ***
  info for this section
```

Example output:

```
[*** Section Header ***\r\n\r\n randomly formatted content\r multiple lines, **** Another Header\r this sections info,*** sub header and its info, ...etc.]
```

which is [string of section, string of section, string of section]
Most of my attempts fail because of complications due to inconsistent opening and closing conditions or the multiline nature of my need.

Here are my closest attempts that either create unwanted elements (like a string containing the closing asterisk of one header and the opening of another) or only grab a header.

This matches the headers:

```
sample.scan(/\*{3}.*/)
```

This matches headers and sections but creates elements from closing and opening asterisks, I don't fully understand the look ahead an behind assertions but I think the solution will look something like this based on my searches for a solution.

```
sample.scan(/(?<=\*{3}).*?(?=\*{3})/m)
```

I'm now working with something to find lines that start with space and or asterisks but it's not there yet!

```
sample.scan(/^(\s+\*+|\*+).*/)
```

Any direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: tom (or is it "twintur"?), whenever you give an example (which is almost always a good thing), please *always* show your desired output. Even when it's not necessary to make your question clear and unambiguous, a quick glance and the example and desired output generally tells the reader what you are trying to do.

Comment: Try `sample.split(/^\s*\*{3}/)`. It's not exactly what you want but it's a good starting point.

Comment: Mark, this works well.  Split removes the delimiter from the output (which may be fine).  For some reason I feel that matching the content is better than splitting it, but this is the most serviceable solution.  This may hold up as as I haven't been able to completely match the content.

Comment: Your example output is an invalid array in Ruby. Please show what it should really look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish what you're looking to do, although if you want to use regex a pattern something such as this might work (depending on the exact text, you might need to tweak it a bit):

```
(.*[*].*.+[^*]*)
```

**Example:**

**http://regex101.com/r/aU0xU1/2**

**Code:**

**http://ideone.com/oMsb50**

Aboout the pattern `(.*[*].*.+[^*]*)`:

```
.*    matches any character (except newline)
       (Between zero and unlimited times),  [greedy]
[*]   matches astertik * the literal character *
.*    matches any character (except newline)
       (Between zero and unlimited times),  [greedy]
.+    matches any character (except newline)
       (Between one and unlimited times),   [greedy]
[^*]* match anything except for an asterik
       (Between zero and unlimited times),  [greedy]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: This is pretty close, let me research exactly what it's doing and tweak.  Great exposure for me, thank you.

Comment: This creates an array with double the elements and appears to match some unnecessary carriage returns or new lines.  I'll keep playing with it.  Thanks!

Comment: @twinturbotom, Try this pattern `(.*[*].*.+[^*]*)` [http://ideone.com/c95AZv](http://ideone.com/c95AZv)

Comment: That does it!  Thank you!  Mind updating your original answer for completeness?  Maybe even a quick break down?  I'm working to understand it right now.

Comment: This was extremely helpful in understanding the combination of characters needed to approach my match.  I already see how I can use this type of pattern in other places too... THANK YOU!

Comment: that bottom image is great!

Answer (score 3):

Ruby's Enumerable includes [`slice_before`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) which is really useful for this sort of task:

```
str = "*** Section Header ***

randomly formatted content
multiple lines

 *** Another Header (some don't end with asterisk and sometimes space will exist before the asterisk set)

This sections info
       **** sub headers sometime occur***
           I'm okay with treating this as normal headers for now.
           I think sub headers may have something consistent about them.


*** Header ***
  info for this section
"
str.split("\n").slice_before(/^\s*\*{3}/).to_a
# => [["*** Section Header ***",
#      "",
#      "randomly formatted content",
#      "multiple lines",
#      ""],
#     [" *** Another Header (some don't end with asterisk and sometimes space will exist before the asterisk set)",
#      "",
#      "This sections info"],
#     ["       **** sub headers sometime occur***",
#      "           I'm okay with treating this as normal headers for now.",
#      "           I think sub headers may have something consistent about them.",
#      "",
#      ""],
#     ["*** Header ***", "  info for this section"]]
```

Using `slice_before` allows me to use a very simple pattern to locate a landmark/target that indicates where the sub-array breaks occur. Using `/^\s*\*{3}/` finds lines that start with a possible string of whitespace followed by three `'*'`. Once found, a new sub-array begins.

If you want each sub-array to actually be a single string instead of an array of lines in the block, `map(&:join)` is your friend:

```
str.split("\n").slice_before(/^\s*\*{3}/).map(&:join)
# => ["*** Section Header ***    randomly formatted content    multiple lines",
#     "     *** Another Header (some don't end with asterisk and sometimes space will exist before the asterisk set)    This sections info",
#     "           **** sub headers sometime occur***               I'm okay with treating this as normal headers for now.               I think sub headers may have something consistent about them.",
#     "    *** Header ***      info for this section    "]
```

And, if you want to strip leading and trailing whitespace you can use `strip` in conjunction with `map`:

```
str.split("\n").slice_before(/^\s*\*{3}/).map{ |sa| sa.join.strip }
# => ["*** Section Header ***    randomly formatted content    multiple lines",
#     "*** Another Header (some don't end with asterisk and sometimes space will exist before the asterisk set)    This sections info",
#     "**** sub headers sometime occur***               I'm okay with treating this as normal headers for now.               I think sub headers may have something consistent about them.",
#     "*** Header ***      info for this section"]
```

or:

```
str.split("\n").slice_before(/^\s*\*{3}/).map{ |sa| sa.map(&:strip).join(' ') }
# => ["*** Section Header ***  randomly formatted content multiple lines ",
#     "*** Another Header (some don't end with asterisk and sometimes space will exist before the asterisk set)  This sections info",
#     "**** sub headers sometime occur*** I'm okay with treating this as normal headers for now. I think sub headers may have something consistent about them.  ",
#     "*** Header *** info for this section "]
```

or:

```
str.split("\n").slice_before(/^\s*\*{3}/).map{ |sa| sa.join.strip.squeeze(' ') }
# => ["*** Section Header *** randomly formatted content multiple lines",
#     "*** Another Header (some don't end with asterisk and sometimes space will exist before the asterisk set) This sections info",
#     "**** sub headers sometime occur*** I'm okay with treating this as normal headers for now. I think sub headers may have something consistent about them.",
#     "*** Header *** info for this section"]
```

depending on what you want to do.

---

> Splitting by "\r" produces a better output on my real file than "\n"

```
str.split(/\r?\n/).slice_before(/^\s*\*{3}/).to_a
```

Use `/\r?\n/`, which is a regular expression that looks for optional carriage-returns followed by a new-line. Windows uses a `"\r\n"` combination to mark the end of a line, whereas Mac OS and *nix use only `"\n"`. By doing this you're not tying your code to being Windows-only.

I don't know if `slice_before` was developed for this particular use, but I've used it for tearing apart text files and breaking them down into paragraphs, and splitting networking device configurations into chunks, which made parsing a lot easier in either case.

Comment: Thank you for this approach.  I've learned a lot from your posts (here and in the past).  I need to spend more time working with these methods and comparing with the others.  The slice_before method does seem like it was developed for this sort of task.  Thank you.  Splitting by "\r" produces a better output on my real file than "\n"; I"ll have to review the differences in my real file and example further.  Thanks.

Comment: You can split on `\r`, but you'll have instantly made your code non-portable. Only Windows uses carriage-return as part of its line-ending these days. See the added code for how to I'd handle this.

Answer (score 0):

```
^((?:[ ]+|[ ]*\*)+.+)$
```

You can try this.Instead of `\s` use `[ ]` as `\s` covers `\n` too.See demo.Grab the captures.

http://regex101.com/r/vR4fY4/14

Comment: Thank you for your response and efforts here.  This didn't work for me.  It took every line and added them as elements in an array.  I'm looking for each element of the array to be content from each section.   Your answer introduces some new concepts for me that I'll look into extending / tailoring for my situation and I will also look to see if my simplified version vs. the real text file is causing the unexpected response.

Comment: @twinturbotom did you check the demo?is the ouput required same as in Demo?

Answer (score 0):

A more readable idea might be to split before the pattern using lookahead:

```
str.split /(?=\n *\*{3})/
```